# How to use python struct package to only unpack first 6 bytes

Tags: python, struct, hex

I would like to use the struct package to just provide me the first 6bytes of some payload because I do not always know the size, e.g.

> b'A\x10VuGe\x00d\x0c\xf4\x06\x0cf\x00'

Following code works if I know the size of the buffer:

```
import struct
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import UTC
import json
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str

data2 = b'A\x10VuGe\x00d\x0c\xf4\x06\x0cf\x00'
devid,hw,sw,bat,ss,distance,interrupt  = struct.unpack('>6sBBHbHb',data2)

print(f"DeviceID={devid.hex()} HW={hw} SW={'.'.join(str(sw))} "
      f"BAT={bat:.3f}mV SignalStrength={-113+2*ss}dBm "
      f"Distance={distance} "
      f"Interrupt={interrupt}")
```

Comment: You can apply the same slice notation to bytes as known from strings.

Comment: I don't get this, can you explain more please?

Answer (score 0):

just use: `data = data[0:14]` and you would have the first 14 bytes..
Than unpack the way you did